# iOS Installation Error: ApplicationVerificationFailed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, air, fdt

I have spent the last 6hrs searching the web for this bugs, I have read and tried many suggested solutions  and still couldn't fix my problem. So lets hope someone can point me to the right direction this time.

I am using FDT to build AIR app, I can test it using iOS Simulator, I can package it and deploy to iTuneConnect but I just can't push it to my iPhone so I can test it. I am sure that my mobileprovision is correct (I check it with XCode 5), the app id is correct, and p12 is good also.

Here is the log I get from XCode console:

```
Mar  9 22:27:32 202-436-0338 installd[17] <Notice>: 0x10050c000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.abcd.bht
Mar  9 22:27:33 202-436-0338 installd[17] <Error>: 0x10050c000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.WPRL4j/foo_extracted/Payload/BHT.app/BHT: 0xe8008015
Mar  9 22:27:33 202-436-0338 installd[17] <Error>: 0x10050c000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.WPRL4j/foo_extracted/Payload/BHT.app
Mar  9 22:27:33 202-436-0338 installd[17] <Error>: 0x10050c000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Mar  9 22:27:33 202-436-0338 mobile_installation_proxy[142] <Error>: 0x10050c000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Mar  9 22:27:33 202-436-0338 mobile_installation_proxy[142] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Mar  9 22:27:33 202-436-0338 mobile_installation_proxy[142] <Error>: 0x10050c000 handle_install: Installation failed: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x12c5121d0 {Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620395}
Mar  9 22:27:33 202-436-0338 installd[17] <Error>: 0x10050c000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
```

[image: Provision file is correct as shown in XCode]

Answer (score 1):

have you installed previously any application on your device with the same bundle identifier?
it may also can cause the problem.
so you can try :

1. delete all adHoc apps from your phone.
2. clean build from Xcode.
3. double check that if you put correct bundle id and selected correct provisioning profiles.
4. your device added to provisioning profile? may be you created first provisioning profile, then added device in developer portal. (Recommended that check your device again in developer portal and create again adhoc profile.)
5. install again

Comment: Yes I have previously installed this app on my device and I did manually deleted it and did all those steps you mention above except number 2 since I build my app with FDT, not with Xcode.